# NUXT / Consola package 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?''

Tags: nuxt.js

I have the following error in "@nuxt/utils/consola" and don't know how to resolve it ?

> const isBadge = logObj.badge ?? logObj.level < 2;
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
> at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1053:16)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:27)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
> at Object. (\node_modules@nuxt\utils\node_modules\consola\dist\index.cjs:5:15)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)

I have already remove "node_module" and "npm install" or "clean cache" but the message always come back.

What can i do ?

EDIT :

When i manually edit the code, i have the message "Error: Cannot find module 'node:util'".

Comment: What Node.js version do you have? (`node -v` command). "Unexpected token" is often because same older versions of Node don't support recent JavaScript language features (`??` was introduced in ES2020, which means you need at least Node.js 14)

Comment: I'm getting a similar error (from typescript-build package)

running node 18